# Android application can't run on Galaxy S4 but can run at Galaxy Ace 2

Tags: java, android, galaxy

The android application that I develop doesn't work on **galaxy s4**.
Everything is pretty normal when I run it. The **MainActivity**(First Page) is fine and working However when I press the button, which will switch to the activity that will retrieve data from web service and publish it on the phone, the application force closes!
I tried the same application at my **galaxy ace 2** and everything is fine, after the button is pressed - it works normally and gives me the correct output. Any ideas what is wrong with my android application?

Here is the code for my **MainActivity(First page) button**:

```
Button recommendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button dateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
recommendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

String packageName = AndroidXMLParsingActivity.class
.getPackage().getName();
String packageAndClassName = AndroidXMLParsingActivity.class
.getName();
Intent intent = new Intent().setClassName(packageName,
packageAndClassName);
startActivity(intent);
}
});
```

And here is the **AndroidXMLParsingActivity** class that will retrieve data from the web service:

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

// All static variables


  static final String URL = "http://api.eventful.com/rest/events/search?app_key=42t54cX7RbrDFczc&location=singapore";
// XML node keys
static final String KEY_EVENT = "event"; // parent node
static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
static final String KEY_DESC = "description";
static final String KEY_URL = "url";
static final String KEY_START_TIME = "start_time";
static final String KEY_VENUE_NAME = "venue_name";
static final String KEY_COUNTRY_NAME = "country_name";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_EVENT);
// looping through all item nodes <item>
for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) {
// creating new HashMap
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
// adding each child node to HashMap key => value
map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
map.put(KEY_URL, parser.getValue(e, KEY_URL));
map.put(KEY_START_TIME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_START_TIME));
map.put(KEY_VENUE_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_VENUE_NAME));
map.put(KEY_COUNTRY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_COUNTRY_NAME));

// adding HashList to ArrayList
menuItems.add(map);
}

// Adding menuItems to ListView
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
R.layout.list_item, new String[] { KEY_TITLE, KEY_DESC, KEY_COUNTRY_NAME,
KEY_VENUE_NAME, KEY_START_TIME }, new int[] {
R.id.title,R.id.description, R.id.countryName, R.id.venueName,
R.id.startTime });

setListAdapter(adapter);

// selecting single ListView item
ListView lv = getListView();

lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
int position, long id) {
// getting values from selected ListItem
String title = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title))
.getText().toString();
String description = ((TextView) view
.findViewById(R.id.description)).getText().toString();

// Starting new intent
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
in.putExtra(KEY_TITLE, title);
in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);

startActivity(in);

}
});
}
}
```

Comment: put some logcat output, so we can isolate the problem, and better help you

Comment: can you show the error? are you sure your galaxy s2 have data enabled?

Comment: @OnurA.07-19 15:35:35.608: E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup(20901): Parent view is not a TextView
07-19 15:35:35.688: E/AndroidRuntime(20901): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-19 15:35:35.688: E/AndroidRuntime(20901): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.androidhive.xmlparsing/com.androidhive.xmlparsing.AndroidXMLParsingActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
07-19 15:35:35.688: E/AndroidRuntime(20901): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)

Comment: @micro.pravi It can work on ace 2 but not S4

Comment: data is enabled on both the device?

Comment: It is enabled for both devices

Answer (score 0):

If `AndroidXMLParsingActivity` is the activity to be opened after the `MainActivity`, why don't you use this code to open the activity.

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, AndroidXMLParsingActivity.class));
```

in place of your code:

```
String packageName = AndroidXMLParsingActivity.class
.getPackage().getName();
String packageAndClassName = AndroidXMLParsingActivity.class
.getName();
Intent intent = new Intent().setClassName(packageName,
packageAndClassName);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Hi, it don't work.

I guess there's something to do with manifest, but I'm not sure about it

Comment: Are you sure about the imports. And the android versions are same on both the devices. If there was a problem with Manifest, it wouldn't have run on any device. But as you said, it is running on one.

Comment: There is no problems with the imports.
As for the android version for S4 it is 4.2.2
and for Ace 2, it is 2.3.6.

Both can run the initial page but after the retrieve data button is clicked, the S4 will have force close error, as for Ace 2, it works well.